# basic mysqli insert query not working

Tags: mysqli

Anyone can spot the problem with this query?
I am stuck on this little part of the project but just can't see the error.

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO item (name, description, buyPrice, price, qty, brandID, primaryCategoryID, secondaryCategoryID, thirdCategoryID, supplierID) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['description']}', '$buyPrice', '$price', '{$_POST['Qty']}', '{$_POST['brandID']}', '{$_POST['primaryCategoryID']}', '{$_POST['secondaryCategoryID']}', '{$_POST['thirdCategoryID']}', '{$_POST['supplierID']}')");
```

the query is just not working.

The following UPDATE query works perfectly tho, and im sure the $_POST variable are passed correctly in both cases:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE item SET name = '{$_POST['editInventoryName']}', description = '{$_POST['editInventoryDescription']}', buyPrice = '$buyPrice', price = '$price', brandID = '{$_POST['editInventoryBrand']}', supplierID = '{$_POST['editInventorySupplier']}', primaryCategoryID = '{$_POST['editInventoryPrimaryCat']}', thirdCategoryID = '{$_POST['editInventoryThirdCat']}', secondaryCategoryID = '{$_POST['editInventorySecondaryCat']}' WHERE id = '{$_POST['editInventoryID']}'");
```

Comment: Look at the way you quote inside the values: `'{$_POST['name']}'`. The single quotes around `name` negate the single quotes around `{$...}`. You probably don't need the single quotes around `name` or around `{$...}`. This also applies to the remaining ones in the list of values.

Comment: Write the query in a vairable `$query` and echo it to see, how the SQL is written, then post in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a $_POST variable was passed empty and therefore the query did not execute.

Sorry for the dumb question coding for too many hours got to this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets around the `$_POST` varibles:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO item (name, description, buyPrice, price, brandID, primaryCategoryID, secondaryCategoryID, thirdCategoryID, supplierID) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['description']."', '".$buyPrice."', '".$price."', '".$_POST['brandID']."', '".$_POST['primaryCatergoryID']."', '".$_POST['secondaryCategoryID']."', '".$_POST['thirdCatgoryID']."', '".$_POST['supplierID']."')");
```

Comment: Is it necessary to remove the backticks?

Comment: He only needs backticks if the column/table names collide with reserved MySQL keywords and symbols.  In this case, they do not.

Comment: You are not wrong. But neither the backticks nor the single quotes are supposed to be a problem based on the codes are written.

Comment: No, it should work, since you have the braces around `$_POST['name']`

Comment: OK you are making a good point.  We don't really know what is going wrong and he should use the error function here.

Comment: Correct. But first this is to check the query itself to be sure, if he has the values in $_POST

Comment: The UPDATE query I have added in original post works...variable are passed correctly.